# "while" and present perfect

Tags: present-perfect

Is the following OK?
Can "while" be used with a present perfect in the main clause?

> John has eaten two platefuls of spaghetti while he is watching football.

Comment: It's syntactically valid, but incredibly "awkward". Obviously you'd only use Present Perfect in the relatively unlikely context where he's *still* watching football (if he's finished, it would be *John **ate** two platefuls...*). And *normally,* even if he's still watching at time of utterance, the speaker probably wouldn't think it was necessary to convey that fact, so he'd probably dump the repeated subject & verb: *John has eaten two platefuls of spaghetti [while] watching football* - which potentially loses the "is still watching" implication, but who cares?

Comment: ...or _while he has been watching football_.